# Reduce decimal value in label

Tags: vb.net, label, decimal

I have a label that shows too many decimal values.

For example,

```
textbox1 = 22  
textbox2 =  7  
label1 = textbox2/textbox1
```

I want `label1` turn to 31.8 but it always turn to 31.8181811818181818881

I have already tried:

```
    Dim label1 As String
    label1 = (CInt(Me.textbox2.Text) / CInt(Me.textbox1.Text)) * 100
    Format(label1, "0.00")
    Form3.label1.Text = label1 + " %"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Acc.** to your comment:

```
@KashishArora yes
```

I will do it in a very very simple way!

### Explanation

We will first simply divide Textbox1 with Textbox2 and store the value in a label and then declare an integer `a` as `label1.text` (it isn't necessary to do it in variable, you can do directly). Then we will use the `Math.Round` control and specify the number of decimals we want (1 or 2).

And then finally, store the value of `a` back to `Label1`.

### Code And Example

```
Label1.Text = Val(TextBox2.Text) / Val(TextBox1.Text)
Dim a As Double = Label1.Text
a = Math.Round(a, 2) '2 is number of decimal places
Label1.Text = a
'All the things you want to do with this.
```

I hope it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format()`...

```
Dim label1 As String
label1 = (CInt(Me.textbox2.Text) / CInt(Me.textbox1.Text)) * 100
label1 = String.Format("{0:0.0}", label1)
Form3.label1.Text = label1 & " %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the combination of `substring` and `lastindexof`

```
label1 = textbox2/textbox1

Dim labelText As String = label1.Text
labelText = labelText.Substring(0, labelText.LastIndexOf(".") +2)  + "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're all making this more complex than it is. [Decimal.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload where you can pass a [standard or custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your case on should use the `F{n}` format specifier where `{n}` is the precision specifier indicating the desired number of decimal places.

```
label1.Text = (Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text) / Decimal.Parse(textbox2.Text)).ToString("F2")
```

Comment: What's so complex in a = math.round(a, 2)?